# Show related category entries from relationship entry

Tags: categories, relationships

I'm trying to list category entries from relationship entry: I'm trying to achieve this result:

```
          CategoryA
          test1

          CategoryB
          test2
          test3
```

but my attempt:

```
    {relationship_field}
      {relationship_field:categories backspace="2"}
        {if parent_id !="0"}
          {category_name}
          {relationship_field:title}
        {/if}
      {/relationship_field:categories}
    {/relationship_field}
```

shows this result:

```
          CategoryA
          test1

          CategoryB
          test2

          CategoryB
          test3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't got a system to test on - but looks like you need to explicitly loop the values that have the category.  I suspect you need to use the '[siblings](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/relationships.html#id27)' tag - something like:

```
{relationship_field}
  {relationship_field:categories backspace="2"}
    {if parent_id !="0"}
      {category_name}
      {relationship_field:siblings field="relationship_field"}
            {relationship_field:siblings:title}
      {/siblings}
      {relationship_field:title}
    {/if}
  {/relationship_field:categories}
{/relationship_field}
```

HTH

Comment: closing tag should be: {/relationship_field:siblings} anyway ended up using embed template